# Message Box pop up not cleared properly

Tags: vb.net

I have an application in VB.net. I am using the msgbox inside the execution of a loop. Now the message box pops up fine, but when i click on "Ok" in the pop up, the message box

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?  It makes no sense to me.

Comment: What after "the message box" ? Please complete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the end of the question is the same as the subject, namely, that in a loop, the message box pops up but when OK is clicked the message box is not "cleared properly".

It sounds like the loop is running tightly enough that the system cannot process any messages and refresh the window.

Without seeing any code, however, this is just speculation and an appropriate solution cannot be given.  You might try adding a .Refresh() call after the message box to the form/window or whatever to get the screen to update.

Please provide more information if possible.